# Is the Persona 5 manga considered canon?

Tags: persona5

Typically anime and manga adaptations of games are not canon, but I was curious as to whether this the case here.

Can anyone shed some light?

PS: Persona 5 is a gorgeous JRPG and I strongly recommend playing it.

Comment: [Persona 4: The Animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persona_4:_The_Animation) was considered to be a faithful adaptation to the game, so it's possible that P5 manga also faithfully adapts the game (just a thought).

Comment: Well coming back here after awhile. Does anyone have any confirmation on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Granted that the content is not that much different from the game (aside from some dialog and translation).

Unless someone can prove otherwise, I do believe that the manga will be considered cannon but with the game as the original source of the material.